# jQuery contentDocument of frame not working on FireFox

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, dom, frame

This line works on Chrome and IE but not on FireFox. In FireFox console I get the message: **ReferenceError: $ is not defined**

```
var lang = $($('#navFrame')[0].contentDocument).find('#languageMenuContainer').eq(0).find('button').html();
```

both on Chrome and IE, the value of lang is: English or Francais, but on FF is not working.
Information: navFrame is

```
<frame id="navFrame" name="navFrame" src="...">
...
```

Thank you

Comment: And on which line is said console error happening? That console error shouldn't be caused by contentDocument usage.

Comment: What makes you think `contentDocument` doesn't work? Reading the error, it seems the problem is that `$` is not defined.

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined on ff console points to this line. and this is the only error i get for the whole code

Comment: NB: This line works perfectly on Chrome and IE

Comment: Does anything before this line use `$`? The error you are getting suggests jQuery isn't loading.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem
In our web sites we use https and FireFox block jQuery because I point to http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js which is not https. point to https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js resolved my problem.
Thanks